# Creating a Wicket header / footer / content layout where only content changes dynamically

Tags: java, wicket

I'm using Wicket and I have followed [this](https://examples7x.wicket.apache.org/template/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.template.pageinheritance.Page1;jsessionid=BD8384CE911894DFBB78790278BC7040?0) guide (and also [this](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/6.x/guide/layout.html) one) to build a webpage template.
My goal is to have a fixed header and footer and a dynamic `<div>` inside `<body>` that change its content when I change page by clicking on some menu links.

So at the end I have done something like this:

**HomePage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title wicket:id="title"> Title </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head> 

  <body>
    <div wicket:id="menu"></div>

    <div wicket:id="homepageContent"></div>

    <div id="content" wicket:id="template" class="">
      <wicket:child/>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/myjs.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**HomePage.java**

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {
    // Title of the current page
    private String pageTitle;

    public HomePage() {
        // dynamic page title
        add(new Label("title", new PropertyModel<>(this, "pageTitle")));

    // ...
    }

    // ...

    public String getPageTitle() {
        return pageTitle;
    }

    public final void setPageTitle(String title) {
        pageTitle = title;
    }
}
```

**Menu.java**

```
public class Menu extends Panel {
    public Menu(String id) {
        super(id);

        add(new BookmarkablePageLink<>("homepageLink", HomePage.class));
        add(new BookmarkablePageLink<>("page1Link", Page1.class));
        add(new BookmarkablePageLink<>("page2Link", Page2.class));
    }
    public Menu(String id, IModel<?> model) {
        super(id, model);
    }
}
```

**Page1.java**

```
public class Page1 extends HomePage {
   public Page1() {
        setPageTitle("Page1");

        // ...
    }
}
```

**Page2.java**

```
public class Page2 extends HomePage {
   public Page2() {
        setPageTitle("Page2");

        // ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that everytime I use my `Menu` to open a page (`Page1` or `Page2`) the browser reloads all resources, I think it's due to `Page1` and `Page2` that are children of `HomePage`.

So, for example, one issue I have is that if I want my `Menu` to keep track of the page I'm currently visiting by setting a `active` class via javascript, I will have troubles because everytime I visit a page the `js` files (and all the others) are downloaded again and I loose all the logic I did.

I just would like to change the content of:

```
<div id="content" wicket:id="template" class="">

</div>
```

without refreshing all the rest of the page.

Is it possible to do that just by changing the Wicket approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is basically a Single Page Application. In this case page inheritance doesn't work well. You need to turn Page1, Page2, etc... into Panels and use AJAX to place them as page content (in your code wicket:id="template") when user clicks menu items.

Comment: Could you give a simple example of this flow?

Comment: Honestly  I don't have any code or example to show, but I would start replacing BookmarkablePageLinks with AjaxLinks that replace the current content panel with the correct one. This should do much of the job.

Answer (score 0):

You should to use `<wicket:extend></wicket:extend>` in parent markup. Something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title wicket:id="title"> Title </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head> 

  <body>
  <wicket:extend>
    <div wicket:id="menu"></div>

    <div wicket:id="homepageContent"></div>

    <div id="content" wicket:id="template" class="">
      <wicket:child/>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/myjs.js"></script>
  </wicket:extend>
  <section id="content">
      <wicket:child/>
  </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

`<wicket:child>` is used inside the parent’s markup to define where the children pages/panels can “inject” their custom markup extending the markup inherited from the parent component.
Now only the child markup will updating, I'm not completly sure, but looks like only child part updating.